# Display Recently Added Custom Post Types with Custom Taxonomy Shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I have taken a few stabs at this and have hit a road block. I will try to be as descriptive as possible...

1. I have a Custom Post Type: Bars
2. I have a Custom Taxonomy associated with Bars called: Location
3. Location has several cities associated with it. e.g. Dallas, Atlanta, Philadelphia, etc.

I have a created a shortcode that currently works with the exception that I cannot figure out how to grab the "terms" associated with "location" and display them in the Recent Post list on the front-end. Only the Thumbnail, Title, and Date are displaying.

Currently I am using `wp_get_recent_posts` but after some reading, should I be using that at all? Or should I be using `WP_Query`?

Here is my code:

```
function recent_cpt_list_display( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'cpt_type' => 'bars',
    'show_posts' => 5,
    'cpt_cat' => 'location',
  ), $atts, 'cpt-recent-posts' );

  global $post;

  $cpt_type = $atts['cpt_type'];
  $show_posts = $atts['show_posts'];
  $cpt_cat = $atts['cpt_cat'];

  $cpt_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'post_type' => $cpt_type,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => $show_posts
  ));

  if ( ! empty( $cpt_posts ) && ! is_wp_error( $cpt_posts ) ) {
    $output = '<ul class="cpt-recent-posts">';

    foreach( $cpt_posts as $cpt_post ){
        $output .= '<li>';
        $output .= '<div class="cpt-recent-posts-thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $cpt_post['ID'], 'thumbnail' ) . '</div>';
        $output .= '<div class="cpt-recent-meta">';
        $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $cpt_post["ID"] ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $cpt_post["post_title"] ) . '" >' . $cpt_post["post_title"].'</a>';
        $output .= '<div class="cpt-meta">' . NEED TO OUTPUT LOCATION HERE . '</div>';
        $output .= '<div class="cpt-post-date">' . get_the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ), $post->ID ) . '</div>';
        $output .= '</div></li>';
      }
      $output .= '<ul>';
     }
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'cpt-recent-posts', 'recent_cpt_list_display' );
```

Any insight as to do this better, I am all ears as I am still learning. I am trying to rely less on using plugins for everything and really want to code as much as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_the_terms` to fetch terms for a specific post:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $cpt_post['ID'], 'location' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    $output .= '<div class="cpt-meta">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $output .= $term->name . ' ';
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: How would I output that in the order within the existing foreach loop?

Comment: The above code would basically replace the whole line where you have `NEED TO OUTPUT LOCATION HERE` right now, so it would be inside your existing `foreach` loop.

Comment: unfortunately I had tried something like that previously but it only dumps out the "location" of the post the shortcode was placed on, not the location of each "Recent Post".

Comment: ah, sorry, see edit above. you were likely not passing the correct post ID. `$post->ID` refers to the post that contains the shortcode, you need to pass `$cpt_post['ID']`, which is the ID of each post in your `foreach` loop.

Comment: thank you, this definitely works. However, my other question... would using `WP_Query` and passing $args be a better solution or is this fine? It seems like a lot of people have different methods of approaching something like this, and with me just starting out learning, I am trying to find out what is "best practice". Thanks again.

Comment: Well, it was close, if a `$term` has more then one word in it, it is splitting them out into separate `<div>'s`

Comment: You just need to open and close the div outside of the term loop, see above. And `wp_get_recent_posts` is fine if it works for your purposes. It's a wrapper that ultimately uses `WP_Query`, as all functions that retrieve posts do.

Comment: hate to be a bother, but what is the deciding factor when `wp_get_recent_posts` isn't the best tool for the job and you should switch to `WP_Query`, that is the part I get lost. BTW, thank you, I have accepted your answer as it works perfectly now.

Comment: As long as it does what you need. Maybe if your arguments were complex you'd need something more flexible.